# Desktop app to browse and copy images with minimal amount of clicks

Tags: windows, file-management, image-viewer

I have folder A with several gigabytes worth of wallpapers. I want to see every one and copy the ones I like to folder B with minimal number of clicks.

What I do right now is have 2 explorer windows open (one with huge preview) and Ctrl+drag images I like. However, this becomes tiresome very quickly.

Any ideas on a software or approach to optimize this procedure?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? Depending on the version, you can view the images by their thumbnail and select & copy them that way

Comment: Well that is mostly what I do now, and it's too slow.

Comment: What's slow about it? I would recommend other applications but, honestly they do the same thing in a slightly different interface

Comment: You have to drag every single image, but no need to worry now, I have almost done tool that will do what I need. Will close the question once I throw it on Github for anyone that comes across same issues as me. Thank you for your help anyways :)

Comment: Alright, what I do just in case you need to do something like this again, is you select each image with holding the control key, then copy them (ctrl + c), and paste them in the other folder (ctrl + v)

Comment: In Windows, you could right click on a file, then use the "Send to" menu. You can customise Send To, to add more destinations. But not sure if that is any quicker, can you set a shortcut key for this?

Answer (score 3):

Since I could not find anything that would sufficiently optimize this task, I made my own tool to do it:

[**ImgBrowseCopy**](https://github.com/fireantik/ImgBrowseCopy)

> Allows you to browse through folder A with large amount of images and copy the ones you like to folder B

<kbd>Enter</kbd> copies the image, <kbd>Space</kbd> shows the next image.

Comment: Please award yourself the answer. This will help others who search this question in future

Answer (score 0):

IrfanView is great for browsing images. You can use its F7/F8 keys to move/copy the images to a set of folders. You can also use FreeCommander which is a two-pane Windows Explorer.